# setAutoGrow() works only on the first page of application, what`s wrong?

Tags: javascript, facebook

In my facebook application I use setAutoGrow() to make page fit to content and it works, but only on the first page, when I go to another page it get height of main page from application starts and doesnt fit new content. What`s wrong?

I`m doing it in this way

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
      appId   : '<?php echo $facebook->getAppId(); ?>',
      channelUrl : '//autosn.net/channel.php', 
      cookie  : true, 
      xfbml   : true, 
      oauth: true
   });

   FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
   ...
```

You can take a look at this problem on http://apps.facebook.com/auto_social/, just go to any other page from main and you see a huge space under content, that left from main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a *little bit* of research of your own¹ you should have been able to find out that setAutoGrow honors it’s name, and *only* **grows** the iframe, but *does not* **shrink** it if the height of the actual page is smaller than that of the previous one.

One solution is to use setSize with a height of 600px (minimum height) at page load, and then call setAutoGrow with a delay (setTimeout) of about 500ms.

---

¹ *Dude, this **really** is an already broadly discussed topic …*

Comment: It`s works. Thanks. And that I didn`t find out answer before this is my fault.